# Setting a custom Security Manager when running JUnit with Gradle

Tags: java, junit, gradle

I'm trying to use a security manager to refrain the developers from writing and reading files in Unit Tests. In order to do that, we think of using a custom Security Manager class. So we created a custom security manager and throw exceptions in checkRead and checkWrite methods.

So when I run the tests from Intellij using the java compiler it runs fine.

As an example I am using the following BeforeClass method:

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void printSecurityManager() throws Exception {

        System.setSecurityManager(new BuildSecurityManager());

    }
```

But when I run this test using `gradle clean test`, the gradle test just hangs and does not respond.

Then, I tried to install the security manager using build.gradle in the following way(just to see if I can actually insert a security manager here):

```
test {
    logger.warn("running tests from gradle")

    SecurityManager manager = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (manager == null) {
        println("there is no security manager!");
    }

    jvmArgs "-Djava.security.manager=java.lang.SecurityManager"
```

But when I tried to run this, I get the following error:

```
:test
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkClassLoaderPermission(ClassLoader.java:1525)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getParent(ClassLoader.java:1371)
    at jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:66)
    at jarjar.org.gradle.process.internal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
:test FAILED
```

So is there a way to insert a custom Security Manager to Gradle for unit tests?

Answer (score 4):

You were onto something ... after a lot of digging I got the following to work in a JUnit test class:

```
public class SomeTest {
    private static final SecurityManager SM = System.getSecurityManager();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startup() throws Exception {

        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkPermission(Permission perm, Object context) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkExit(int status) {
                String message = "System exit requested with error " + status;
                throw new SecurityException(message);
            }
        });
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void shutdown(){
        System.setSecurityManager(SM);
    }

    @Test(expected=SecurityException.class)
    public void someTestThatSystemExits()
    {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Background links:

- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-build-process-hangs-when-system-setsecuritymanager-new-securitymanager-is-called/11670
- https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2170
- http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Infinite-wait-running-tests-td5561210.html
- https://discuss.gradle.org/t/java-lang-internalerror-could-not-create-securitymanager-jarjar-org-gradle-process-internal-child-bootstrapsecuritymanager/2478
- https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2759
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html

It was also helpful to run with the -i and -d flags:

- e.g. `gradle test -i`

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of second problem thanks to one of my coworker. The cause of AccessControlException is the default SecurityManager provided by java.lang does not allow an application to get the class loader. After gradle installs the security manager, it still tries to get the class loader, hence the error.

So the solution is either you have to provide a security policy file with SecurityManager, or you have to provide a custom implementation of SecurityManager.

I haven't found a solution for the hang problem yet.